# OpenJDK8 and JavaFX on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, gradle, java-8, java-11

I would like to run a JavaFX application on macOS that has only OpenJDK8:

- I searched on the internet and I only found solutions for Linux (with apt-get),
- I cannot upgrade to OpenJDK>8 and I cannot switch to Oracle distributions (context constraints).

** Edit **
The problem is that if I run the application with OracleSDK8 it works perfectly fine. But if I run it with OpenJDK8 I have problems when including JavaFX. For example:

```
FilterEditor.java:6: error: package javafx.scene.input does not exist
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
```

I'm using a Gradle script

```
jar {
     if(JavaVersion.current() >= JavaVersion.VERSION_11){
       apply plugin: 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin'
       javafx {
        version = "11"
        modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.swing' ]
      }
      }else if(JavaVersion.current() != JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8){
        throw new GradleException("This build script must be run with java 8 or a java version >= 11")
      }
  destinationDir = projectDir
  manifest.attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
  baseName = 'XXX'
  from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  }
}
```

But if fails if I use OpenJDK8.

Comment: And...what is the problem? Installing OpenJDK 8?

Comment: @dan1st the JavaFX part seems to be missing on MacOS for OpenJDK 8.

Comment: You are right @dan1st (the problem was very clear in my mind). I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are several providers of OpenJDK + JavaFX. E.g. you can download that from Azul: https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?version=java-8-lts&os=macos&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk-fx

Nevertheless you should try to upgrade to a more recent version of Java/FX.

Comment: In other words: JavaFX is not a part of OpenJDK. You can download OpenJFX and include it in the program or use an OpenJDK version that includes OpenJFX.

Comment: @dan1st This is not completely true because you can only add JavaFX as an external dependency for Java >= 11. For Java 8 it is better to look for a distribution which does contains JavaFX already.

Comment: Azul doesn't contain JavaFx anymore